# python scrapy quitar los espacios en blanco de la respuesta

Tags: python, scrapy

Estoy intentando hacer un script con scrapy y no soy capaz de qué el método strip me quite los espacios en blanco...
debería ser un string pero es un objeto. ¿Alguna manera de hacerlo?

```
import scrapy

class GamesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "games"
    start_urls = [
        'myurl',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for game in response.css('ol#products-list li.item'):
            yield {
                'name': game.css('h2.product-name a::text').extract_first().strip(),
                'age': game.css('.list-price ul li:nth-child(1)::text').extract_first(),
                'players': game.css('.list-price ul li:nth-child(2)::text').extract_first(),
                'duration': game.css('.list-price ul li:nth-child(3)::text').extract_first(),
                'dimensions': game.css('.list-price ul li:nth-child(4)::text').extract_first()
            }
```

Comment: Traduce también el titulo, por favor ^^

Comment: Si quitas `.strip()` ¿qué es lo que te guarda en `'name'`? Quizás no sea una cadena como pensabas. Podría ser incluso `None` si no encontró ningún elemento con ese selector.

Comment: creo que es el none por que esto funciona:
game.css('.list-price ul li:nth-child(2)::text').extract_first(default='').strip()
pero deberia existir una mejor forma de hacerlo que ponerle el default no?

Comment: @user1551211 En una sola línea no se me ocurre una forma mejor.

Answer (score 3):

Claro que puedes usar strip, o también puedes hacerlo a nivel del `Selector` con `xpath` usando la función `normalize-space`:

```
game.xpath('normalize-space(.//h2[contains(@class, "product-name")]//a/text())').extract_first(default='')
```

También recuerda usar `extract_first(default='')` si es que quieres siempre un string como respuesta ya que `extract_first` puede también retornar `None` cuando nada fue encontrado.